# WHERE column contains single word

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use SQL `like` to only display single words that are in a particular column of any row? For example, suppose I have the following rows in column1.

```
Column1

put return
need return
got return
bring return
server
client
```

The single-words output I would like is:

```
server
client
```

Can this be accomplish using `like`? I know this can be accomplished using regular expressions, but if possible, I would prefer using `LIKE`.

Comment: Good beginner question. I have never needed this. If you have mutiple words in a column and you want to operate on it, then you should really change your database design. And also inform yourself about normal forms. The 3rd one is the one that you should prefer to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `not like`:

```
where col not like '% %'
```

Comment: This solution would yield the **WRONG** result if your **single word** is either presided or followed by a blank. The solution posted by sagi is the correct one if you TRIM the value (meaning remove blanks from beginning and end of value, and only then check if there is a blank in-between).

Comment: @FDavidov . . . If that is an issue, then the OP should use `trim(col) not like '% %'`.

Comment: Nope. Both should be used as: `where LOCATE(' ',TRIM(column1)) = 0` (here I'm using sagi's proposal).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE Column1 NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Or:

```
WHERE LOCATE(' ',Column1) = 0
```

Comment: Ops, did the opposite @FDavidov